# Side-by-side stacked barplot with facetting using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

The majority of information I can find on side-by-side stacked barplots deals with instances in where some variable (number of side-by-side bars) are repeated for each variable along the x-axis - see: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084775/side-by-side-barplot-with-ggplot), [2](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-11-bar-charts/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070547/ggplot-side-by-side-geom-bar), [4](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/creating-stacked-barplot-and-grouped-barplot-in-r-using-base-graphics-no-ggplot2/), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158230/barplot-with-2-variables-side-by-side), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305023/how-to-get-a-barplot-with-several-variables-side-by-side-grouped-by-a-factor). In these cases they use ggplot with `besides=TRUE`.

I have a more complex example which I believe will require faceting like these two examples: [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429223/stacked-bar-chart-with-side-by-side-in-r-ggplot) & [8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774632/how-to-produce-stacked-bars-within-grouped-barchart-in-r).

Quick background (for those interested in the *why?*):
I'm trying to compare the efficiency of a proteomics protocol that enriches for chromatin by comparing to the proportion of nuclear proteins found in the core/whole proteome experiments for 4 cell lines. to do this I used The Human Protein Atlas to annotate proteins by their subcellular location and compare nuclear proteins from chromatin-enrichment to whole-enrichment. However, the chromatin-enrichment protocol was 1D-shotgun while the whole proteome data was 2D-shotgun with 50 fractions. In layman terms this means the whole/core proteome data is a more expensive experiment done at higher coverage. Therefore, it wouldn't make sense to look at absolute proportion though because the overall amount of found proteins would be higher in the whole proteome pull-downs (see figure: [absolute protein comparison sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucMLd.jpg)). To circumvent this issue I divided by the total number of proteins found in each pull-down to get relative proportion of proteins from each subcellular location.

Using these relative proportions I've produced a stacked barplot of the following data in my [gist](https://gist.github.com/moldach/8cf6aeaaa61b64229d11ec55c19524b3) with the following code:

```
df1 <- read.csv("data.csv") # Load data.frame of the data 
df2 <- melt(df1,                                # Reshape the data from 
            id.vars = "subcellular_location",   # wide format into long format 
            variable.name = "cell_line",        # (i.e. tidy data)
            value.name = "relative_proportion")
```

For some reason this didn't change the variable name or value name (headers) - they are called "variable" and "value" still? So I had to rename column headers via the following.

```
names(df2) <- c("subcellular_location", "cell_line", "relative_proportion")
```

As there are many subcellular locations I needed to custom add colors, furthermore I grouped them by similar locations (e.g. nuclear in blue).

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = cell_line, y = percentage, fill = subcellular_location),
           data = df2, stat="identity") 

p + 
  coord_flip() +  
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#bd5db0","#9ae17c", "#be0024", "#7388ff", "#c456b7", 
                               "#8ed470", "#7ec361", "#7d7304", "#f87a00", "#d543c7", 
                               "#bead47", "#d148c3", "#da8836", "#e28504", "#d93eca", 
                               "#c720b9", "#bc07ae", "#a40098", "#9a008e", "#e8d448", 
                               "#104ed7", "#2c4ecc", "#00428c", "#393c6d", "#173b8f", 
                               "#3f4c96", "#9ba2f5", "#727bcc", "#e59c5f", "#790000", 
                               "#045d00", "#f9ad6f"))
```

See image here: [stacked barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iU0r.png)

The core proteome pull-downs are highlighted in yellow. Ideally what I would like to do is facet this barplot into 4 sections - one for each cell line. I followed the instructions from reference 7 for faceting but am getting an error.

First I split my dataframe into 4 separate tidy dataframes (e.g. below):

```
K562 <- read.csv("K562-relative.csv")
K562 <- melt(K562, id.vars = "subcellular_location") # Reshape the data into tidy form
names(K562) <- c("subcellular_location", "cell_line", "relative_proportion")
```

etc.

Than I created a vector for cell line:

```
cell <- sample(c("HAP1","K562","A673","MDS"))
```

When I try the following code I get an error:

```
ref_by_cell <- data.frame(HAP1 = HAP1, K562 = K562, A673 = A673, MDS = MDS, cell = cell)
```

> Error in data.frame(HAP1 = HAP1, K562 = K562, A673 = A673, MDS = MDS,
>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 576, 544, 64, 4

I would appreciate any help with faceting or alternative ideas for displaying this information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want, but if you want to facet by the first part of each cell_line value...

```
# add faceting variable to df2
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(cell = stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(cell_line, "^[^\\.|_]+"))

# facet by cell, specifying free scales / space on the y-axis
ggplot(data = df2, 
       aes(x = cell_line, y = relative_proportion, fill = subcellular_location)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(cell~., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#bd5db0","#9ae17c", "#be0024", "#7388ff", "#c456b7", 
                               "#8ed470", "#7ec361", "#7d7304", "#f87a00", "#d543c7", 
                               "#bead47", "#d148c3", "#da8836", "#e28504", "#d93eca", 
                               "#c720b9", "#bc07ae", "#a40098", "#9a008e", "#e8d448", 
                               "#104ed7", "#2c4ecc", "#00428c", "#393c6d", "#173b8f", 
                               "#3f4c96", "#9ba2f5", "#727bcc", "#e59c5f", "#790000", 
                               "#045d00", "#f9ad6f")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

[image: plot]

Data (copied from your gist link; next time please use dput so that others can reproduce your example more easily):

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(subcellular_location = c("actinFilaments", "aggresome", 
"cellJunctions", "centrosome", "cytokineticBridge", "cytoplasmicBodies", 
"cytosol", "endoplasmicReticulum", "endosome", "focalAdhesion", 
"golgiApparatus", "intermediateFilaments", "lipidDroplets", "lysosomes", 
"microtubuleEnds", "microtubuleOrganizingCenter", "microtubules", 
"midbodyRing", "midbody", "mitochondria", "mitoticSpindle", "nuclearBodies", 
"nuclearMembrane", "nuclearSpeckles", "nucleliFibrallar", "nucleoli", 
"nucleoplasm", "nucleus", "peroxisomes", "plasmaMembrane", "rodsAndRings", 
"vesicles"), HAP1_P5242 = c(0.009581882, 0.000338753, 0.011033682, 
0.015824623, 0.003774681, 0.00232288, 0.227013163, 0.024535424, 
0.001258227, 0.005807201, 0.04229578, 0.008710801, 0.0014518, 
0.001064654, 0.00029036, 0.006484708, 0.013646922, 0.000483933, 
0.001064654, 0.063637244, 0.00087108, 0.02303523, 0.013646922, 
0.024535424, 0.013259775, 0.054587689, 0.195509098, 0.101480836, 
0.00174216, 0.058072009, 0.000822687, 0.071815718), HAP1.wt_P8255.1 = c(0.0176, 
0, 0.0032, 0.0096, 0, 0.0032, 0.3664, 0.0912, 0.008, 0.0032, 
0.0128, 0, 0, 0.0064, 0, 0.0032, 0.0288, 0, 0, 0.0528, 0, 0.0128, 
0.0048, 0.0096, 0, 0.0496, 0.1552, 0.0576, 0, 0.064, 0.0016, 
0.0384), HAP1.wt_P8255.2 = c(0.013179572, 0, 0, 0.008237232, 
0, 0.004942339, 0.36738056, 0.098846788, 0.003294893, 0.003294893, 
0.016474465, 0.001647446, 0, 0.004942339, 0, 0.003294893, 0.029654036, 
0, 0, 0.05107084, 0, 0.009884679, 0.004942339, 0.011532125, 0, 
0.044481054, 0.154859967, 0.05601318, 0, 0.064250412, 0.001647446, 
0.046128501), HAP1.wt_P8254.1 = c(0.012841091, 0, 0, 0.006420546, 
0.001605136, 0.004815409, 0.362760835, 0.08988764, 0.001605136, 
0.004815409, 0.017656501, 0.003210273, 0, 0.003210273, 0, 0.004815409, 
0.032102729, 0, 0, 0.04975923, 0, 0.011235955, 0.003210273, 0.011235955, 
0, 0.04975923, 0.160513644, 0.060995185, 0, 0.069020867, 0.001605136, 
0.036918138), HAP1.wt_P8254.2 = c(0.015873016, 0, 0, 0.00952381, 
0.001587302, 0.004761905, 0.357142857, 0.103174603, 0.003174603, 
0.003174603, 0.014285714, 0.001587302, 0.001587302, 0.003174603, 
0, 0.003174603, 0.03015873, 0, 0, 0.055555556, 0, 0.012698413, 
0.006349206, 0.012698413, 0, 0.050793651, 0.152380952, 0.063492063, 
0, 0.057142857, 0.001587302, 0.034920635), HAP1.kd_P8253.1 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.270270271, 0.027027028, 0, 0, 0.027027028, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.054054053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.054054053, 0, 0.054054053, 
0.405405405, 0.027027028, 0, 0, 0, 0.081081081), HAP1.kd_P8253.2 = c(0.021381579, 
0, 0.003289474, 0.013157895, 0, 0.003289474, 0.368421053, 0.100328947, 
0.004934211, 0.003289474, 0.013157895, 0.003289474, 0, 0.006578947, 
0, 0.001644737, 0.027960526, 0, 0, 0.046052632, 0, 0.011513158, 
0.004934211, 0.009868421, 0, 0.050986842, 0.15131579, 0.050986842, 
0, 0.065789474, 0.001644737, 0.036184211), HAP1.kd_P8252.1 = c(0.018518518, 
0, 0.00308642, 0.010802469, 0, 0.00462963, 0.354938272, 0.092592593, 
0.00617284, 0.00462963, 0.018518518, 0, 0.00154321, 0.00462963, 
0, 0.00617284, 0.026234568, 0, 0, 0.043209877, 0, 0.015432099, 
0.00308642, 0.015432099, 0, 0.049382716, 0.154320988, 0.061728395, 
0, 0.063271605, 0.00154321, 0.040123457), HAP1.kd_P8252.2 = c(0.012965964, 
0, 0, 0.011345219, 0.001620746, 0.003241491, 0.367909238, 0.095623987, 
0.003241491, 0.004862237, 0.017828201, 0.003241491, 0, 0.004862237, 
0, 0.003241491, 0.030794165, 0, 0, 0.051863857, 0, 0.016207455, 
0.003241491, 0.009724473, 0, 0.04376013, 0.1636953, 0.055105348, 
0, 0.064829822, 0.001620746, 0.02917342), HAP1.kd_P8249.1 = c(0.010309278, 
0.001718213, 0, 0.006872852, 0, 0.005154639, 0.197594502, 0.091065292, 
0.001718213, 0, 0.013745704, 0.005154639, 0.001718213, 0.001718213, 
0, 0, 0.027491409, 0, 0, 0.054982818, 0, 0.017182131, 0.013745704, 
0.060137457, 0, 0.082474227, 0.240549828, 0.094501718, 0, 0.04467354, 
0, 0.027491409), HAP1.kd_P8249.2 = c(0.010752688, 0, 0, 0.007168459, 
0, 0.003584229, 0.20609319, 0.084229391, 0.001792115, 0, 0.007168459, 
0.005376344, 0, 0.001792115, 0, 0, 0.03046595, 0, 0, 0.069892473, 
0, 0.019713262, 0.014336918, 0.064516129, 0, 0.08781362, 0.224014337, 
0.096774194, 0, 0.039426523, 0, 0.025089606), HAP1.kd_P8248.1 = c(0.007207207, 
0, 0.001801802, 0.007207207, 0, 0.003603604, 0.198198198, 0.099099099, 
0, 0, 0.009009009, 0.007207207, 0, 0, 0, 0.001801802, 0.025225225, 
0, 0, 0.061261261, 0, 0.021621622, 0.016216216, 0.068468468, 
0, 0.079279279, 0.234234234, 0.093693694, 0.001801802, 0.028828829, 
0, 0.034234234), HAP1.kd_P8248.2 = c(0.005272408, 0.001757469, 
0, 0.008787346, 0, 0.005272408, 0.202108963, 0.09314587, 0, 0, 
0.014059754, 0.005272408, 0, 0, 0, 0.001757469, 0.029876977, 
0, 0, 0.056239016, 0, 0.021089631, 0.014059754, 0.065026362, 
0, 0.086115993, 0.228471002, 0.094903339, 0.001757469, 0.036906854, 
0, 0.028119508), HAP1.wt_P8247.1 = c(0.016333938, 0, 0, 0.001814882, 
0, 0.005444646, 0.197822141, 0.09800363, 0.001814882, 0, 0.007259528, 
0.005444646, 0, 0.001814882, 0, 0.001814882, 0.030852995, 0, 
0, 0.061705989, 0, 0.021778584, 0.012704174, 0.065335753, 0, 
0.087114338, 0.234119782, 0.096188748, 0, 0.029038113, 0, 0.023593466
), HAP1.wt_P8247.2 = c(0.011173184, 0, 0, 0.003724395, 0, 0.003724395, 
0.197392924, 0.098696462, 0.001862197, 0, 0.009310987, 0.005586592, 
0, 0.001862197, 0, 0.001862197, 0.029795158, 0, 0, 0.059590317, 
0, 0.018621974, 0.013035382, 0.067039106, 0, 0.08566108, 0.240223464, 
0.096834264, 0, 0.029795158, 0, 0.024208566), HAP1.wt_P8246.1 = c(0.008880995, 
0, 0, 0.005328597, 0.003552398, 0.003552398, 0.195381883, 0.090586146, 
0, 0, 0.005328597, 0.008880995, 0, 0, 0, 0.001776199, 0.030195382, 
0, 0, 0.051509769, 0, 0.023090586, 0.01598579, 0.063943162, 0, 
0.097690941, 0.245115453, 0.097690941, 0, 0.026642984, 0, 0.024866785
), HAP1.wt_P8246.2 = c(0.009025271, 0, 0.001805054, 0.005415162, 
0, 0.003610108, 0.19133574, 0.088447653, 0, 0.001805054, 0.012635379, 
0.007220217, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.028880866, 0, 0, 0.048736462, 0, 0.019855596, 
0.027075812, 0.066787004, 0, 0.084837545, 0.241877256, 0.09566787, 
0, 0.028880866, 0, 0.036101083), HAP1_P7964.1 = c(0.010040907, 
0, 0.007437709, 0.017106731, 0.002975084, 0.003346969, 0.211230941, 
0.040535515, 0.002603198, 0.005950167, 0.023056898, 0.00818148, 
0.001115656, 0.002231313, 0.000743771, 0.005950167, 0.014503533, 
0, 0.000743771, 0.065451841, 0.001115656, 0.023056898, 0.018966158, 
0.031610264, 0, 0.065451841, 0.223875046, 0.105243585, 0.002603198, 
0.051692079, 0.001487542, 0.051692079), MDS_P7246 = c(0.008080031, 
0.000384763, 0.005386687, 0.012889573, 0.002885725, 0.002500962, 
0.204116968, 0.035013467, 0.002116199, 0.00461716, 0.030973451, 
0.008272412, 0.001539053, 0.001539053, 0.000192382, 0.003270489, 
0.01250481, 0.000192382, 0.000961908, 0.082724125, 0.000577145, 
0.025971528, 0.018661023, 0.030011543, 0.013851481, 0.065217391, 
0.214313197, 0.108310889, 0.002116199, 0.048095421, 0.000577145, 
0.052135437), MDS.L_P7246.1 = c(0.008308003, 0.000202634, 0.006079027, 
0.013373858, 0.003039513, 0.002228976, 0.207294805, 0.036068891, 
0.002026342, 0.004660587, 0.030800401, 0.008308003, 0.001621074, 
0.001621074, 0.000202634, 0.003039513, 0.012563322, 0.000202634, 
0.001013171, 0.081458956, 0.000405268, 0.026950351, 0.018034445, 
0.030395133, 1.34e-07, 0.065450852, 0.218642321, 0.109017209, 
0.002228976, 0.050050652, 0.000810537, 0.053900702), A673_P6591 = c(0.01081944, 
0.000354736, 0.008158922, 0.013125222, 0.003015254, 0.003015254, 
0.202554097, 0.035118836, 0.002128414, 0.006207875, 0.036183044, 
0.006917347, 0.000886839, 0.001596311, 0.000709471, 0.004788932, 
0.013657325, 0.000177368, 0.001064207, 0.069882937, 0.000709471, 
0.025186236, 0.015253636, 0.029265697, 0.013125222, 0.06385243, 
0.207875133, 0.106598084, 0.002305782, 0.056580348, 0.000354736, 
0.058531394), A673_P6591.1 = c(0.011204482, 0.000186741, 0.008403361, 
0.01363212, 0.003174603, 0.002614379, 0.203361345, 0.036414566, 
0.002054155, 0.006162465, 0.036788049, 0.006722689, 0.000933707, 
0.001680672, 0.000746965, 0.004668534, 0.01363212, 0.000186741, 
0.001120448, 0.069467787, 0.000560224, 0.025957049, 0.014752568, 
0.029505135, 0, 0.064239029, 0.212885154, 0.108496732, 0.002427638, 
0.05751634, 0.000373483, 0.060130719), K562_P535 = c(0.008616975, 
0.000143616, 0.007755278, 0.011202068, 0.002441476, 0.003303174, 
0.278471923, 0.038776389, 0.00229786, 0.006031883, 0.033031739, 
0.00689358, 0.003159558, 0.00229786, 0.000287233, 0.004164871, 
0.012638231, 0.000287233, 0.000574465, 0.090621858, 0.000574465, 
0.015941405, 0.009478673, 0.021255206, 0.009909522, 0.047536981, 
0.181243717, 0.083871894, 0.002441476, 0.055292259, 0.00114893, 
0.0583082), K562_P5494.1 = c(0.008692853, 0.000321957, 0.008692853, 
0.012395364, 0.002736639, 0.002736639, 0.212813909, 0.032356729, 
0.001448809, 0.004990341, 0.033000644, 0.007405023, 0.001448809, 
0.001448809, 0.000160979, 0.004990341, 0.013039279, 0, 0.001126851, 
0.074050225, 0.000643915, 0.027849324, 0.01545396, 0.029459111, 
0, 0.065035415, 0.216355441, 0.111719253, 0.002092724, 0.051996137, 
0.000804894, 0.054732775), K562_P5464.1 = c(0.009412153, 0.000495376, 
0.008256275, 0.013705416, 0.002476882, 0.002476882, 0.20673712, 
0.032529723, 0.001486129, 0.004788639, 0.034180978, 0.007595773, 
0.001155878, 0.001321004, 0.000330251, 0.005284016, 0.012714663, 
0.000330251, 0.000990753, 0.073811096, 0.000660502, 0.02823646, 
0.016017173, 0.029722589, 0, 0.06489432, 0.217635403, 0.110634082, 
0.002146631, 0.052179657, 0.000825627, 0.056968296), K562_P5359.1 = c(0.00740349, 
0, 0.005288207, 0.005288207, 0.001057641, 0.003172924, 0.225806452, 
0.063987308, 0.003172924, 0.004230566, 0.022739291, 0.005817028, 
0.002644104, 0.002644104, 0, 0.003701745, 0.013749339, 0, 0.000528821, 
0.099947118, 0, 0.015864622, 0.020095188, 0.037546272, 0, 0.080909572, 
0.196192491, 0.090957166, 0.002115283, 0.040719196, 0.000528821, 
0.043892121), K562_P5359.2 = c(0.007903056, 0, 0.004741834, 0.006322445, 
0.001580611, 0.002107482, 0.223393045, 0.062170706, 0.002634352, 
0.004741834, 0.023709168, 0.005795574, 0.002634352, 0.002634352, 
0, 0.003688093, 0.014752371, 0, 0, 0.103266596, 0, 0.017386723, 
0.021601686, 0.036354057, 0, 0.079030558, 0.192834563, 0.090621707, 
0.002107482, 0.042676502, 0.00052687, 0.044783983), K562_P5358.1 = c(0.007462687, 
0, 0.00533049, 0.005863539, 0.001599147, 0.003731343, 0.229744136, 
0.064498934, 0.003198294, 0.004264392, 0.024520256, 0.005863539, 
0.003198294, 0.002132196, 0, 0.003731343, 0.015458422, 0, 0, 
0.101812367, 0, 0.015991471, 0.019189765, 0.036247335, 0, 0.077292111, 
0.191364606, 0.087953092, 0.002132196, 0.041577825, 0.000533049, 
0.045309168), K562_P5358.2 = c(0.006546645, 0, 0.005455537, 0.007637752, 
0.001636661, 0.003273322, 0.225859247, 0.063829787, 0.003273322, 
0.003818876, 0.024549918, 0.007092199, 0.002182215, 0.002727769, 
0, 0.003818876, 0.015275505, 0, 0, 0.106382979, 0, 0.016912166, 
0.01745772, 0.038188762, 0, 0.074195308, 0.195853792, 0.089470813, 
0.001636661, 0.040370977, 0.000545554, 0.042007638), K562_P5357.1 = c(0.007057546, 
0, 0.004885993, 0.00597177, 0.001085776, 0.003257329, 0.231813246, 
0.06514658, 0.003257329, 0.004343105, 0.024972856, 0.00597177, 
0.003257329, 0.002171553, 0, 0.003800217, 0.014115092, 0, 0, 
0.118892508, 0, 0.01194354, 0.016829533, 0.030944625, 0, 0.07383279, 
0.184039088, 0.086862106, 0.002171553, 0.049402823, 0.000542888, 
0.043431053), K562_P5357.2 = c(0.008086253, 0, 0.003773585, 0.006469003, 
0.001617251, 0.003234501, 0.23180593, 0.063072776, 0.003773585, 
0.003234501, 0.023180593, 0.005929919, 0.003234501, 0.002695418, 
0, 0.003773585, 0.014555256, 0, 0, 0.116442049, 0, 0.01509434, 
0.017789757, 0.035579515, 0, 0.071698113, 0.189757412, 0.085714286, 
0.002156334, 0.044743935, 0.000539084, 0.042048518), K562_P5356.1 = c(0.006292906, 
0, 0.005148741, 0.004576659, 0.001716247, 0.002860412, 0.215675057, 
0.070366133, 0.003432494, 0.003432494, 0.025743707, 0.005720824, 
0.003432494, 0.002860412, 0, 0.004576659, 0.016018307, 0, 0, 
0.127002288, 0, 0.01201373, 0.016590389, 0.03375286, 0, 0.076659039, 
0.183638444, 0.086956522, 0.001716247, 0.044622426, 0.000572082, 
0.044622426), K562_P5356.2 = c(0.00755814, 0, 0.004069767, 0.004651163, 
0.001744186, 0.002325581, 0.21627907, 0.070930233, 0.002906977, 
0.004069767, 0.025, 0.005813953, 0.003488372, 0.002906977, 0, 
0.004069767, 0.015697674, 0, 0, 0.125581395, 0, 0.013953488, 
0.015697674, 0.035465116, 0, 0.073837209, 0.190697674, 0.08372093, 
0.001744186, 0.045348837, 0.000581395, 0.041860465), K562_P5355.1 = c(0.009320175, 
0, 0.003289474, 0.007675439, 0.001096491, 0.002741228, 0.285087719, 
0.059210526, 0.003837719, 0.006030702, 0.023026316, 0.003837719, 
0.003837719, 0.003289474, 0, 0.003289474, 0.016995614, 0.000548246, 
0, 0.094298246, 0, 0.014254386, 0.012061404, 0.026315789, 0, 
0.052631579, 0.175438596, 0.08497807, 0.001096491, 0.057017544, 
0.000548246, 0.048245614), K562_P5355.2 = c(0.008210181, 0, 0.004378763, 
0.009304871, 0.001094691, 0.002189382, 0.280788177, 0.056376574, 
0.003284072, 0.005473454, 0.024630542, 0.004378763, 0.003284072, 
0.003284072, 0, 0.004378763, 0.016967707, 0, 0, 0.100164204, 
0, 0.014778325, 0.012588944, 0.028461959, 0, 0.053639847, 0.172961138, 
0.084838533, 0.001642036, 0.054187192, 0.000547345, 0.048166393
), K562_P5269.1 = c(0.007308161, 0, 0.003045067, 0.007917174, 
0.001218027, 0.00365408, 0.228989038, 0.071863581, 0.00365408, 
0.004263094, 0.017661389, 0.007308161, 0.002436054, 0.003045067, 
0, 0.002436054, 0.017052375, 0, 0, 0.107186358, 0, 0.015834348, 
0.020097442, 0.033495737, 0, 0.085261876, 0.18453106, 0.091961023, 
0.002436054, 0.040194884, 0.001218027, 0.03593179), K562_P5269.2 = c(0.006234414, 
0, 0.00436409, 0.006234414, 0.002493766, 0.002493766, 0.224438903, 
0.073566085, 0.003117207, 0.002493766, 0.018703242, 0.006857855, 
0.002493766, 0.003117207, 0, 0.001246883, 0.015586035, 0, 0, 
0.109725686, 0, 0.015586035, 0.018703242, 0.034289277, 0, 0.082294264, 
0.195760598, 0.092892768, 0.003117207, 0.039276808, 0.000623441, 
0.034289277), K562_P5268.1 = c(0.004635762, 0, 0.00397351, 0.007284768, 
0.001986755, 0.002649007, 0.214569536, 0.071523179, 0.00397351, 
0.002649007, 0.01986755, 0.007284768, 0.003311258, 0.003311258, 
0, 0.003311258, 0.016556291, 0, 0, 0.104635762, 0, 0.017880795, 
0.018543046, 0.039735099, 0, 0.090066225, 0.195364238, 0.091390728, 
0.001986755, 0.039735099, 0.000662252, 0.033112583), K562_P5268.2 = c(0.005242464, 
0, 0.002621232, 0.00655308, 0.002621232, 0.00327654, 0.216251638, 
0.070117955, 0.00327654, 0.00327654, 0.020969856, 0.008519004, 
0.002621232, 0.001965924, 0, 0.002621232, 0.018348624, 0, 0, 
0.108781127, 0, 0.015727392, 0.020314548, 0.040629096, 0, 0.087811271, 
0.190039319, 0.090432503, 0.001965924, 0.040629096, 0.000655308, 
0.034731324)), .Names = c("subcellular_location", "HAP1_P5242", 
"HAP1.wt_P8255.1", "HAP1.wt_P8255.2", "HAP1.wt_P8254.1", "HAP1.wt_P8254.2", 
"HAP1.kd_P8253.1", "HAP1.kd_P8253.2", "HAP1.kd_P8252.1", "HAP1.kd_P8252.2", 
"HAP1.kd_P8249.1", "HAP1.kd_P8249.2", "HAP1.kd_P8248.1", "HAP1.kd_P8248.2", 
"HAP1.wt_P8247.1", "HAP1.wt_P8247.2", "HAP1.wt_P8246.1", "HAP1.wt_P8246.2", 
"HAP1_P7964.1", "MDS_P7246", "MDS.L_P7246.1", "A673_P6591", "A673_P6591.1", 
"K562_P535", "K562_P5494.1", "K562_P5464.1", "K562_P5359.1", 
"K562_P5359.2", "K562_P5358.1", "K562_P5358.2", "K562_P5357.1", 
"K562_P5357.2", "K562_P5356.1", "K562_P5356.2", "K562_P5355.1", 
"K562_P5355.2", "K562_P5269.1", "K562_P5269.2", "K562_P5268.1", 
"K562_P5268.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L
))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for the help! Sorry it took me a while to respond but I had some other projects that were pressing. This is what I had envisioned and it looks wonderful :)