# I want a side by side barplor (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two columns in a data.frame. lets say one is called "before" and the other is "after". each of these 2 factors has 5 levels (very satisfied, satisfied, somehow, dissatisfied, very dissatisfied).

This is the data:

```
dat <- structure(list(before = structure(c(2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("very satisfied", 
"satisfied", "somehow", "dissatisfied", "very dissatisfied"), class = "factor"), 
    after = structure(c(3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("very satisfied", 
    "satisfied", "somehow", "dissatisfied", "very dissatisfied"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How to build a side by side by plot so that for each of those 5 levels, there are 2 bars (before and after) side by side represented?

Comment: You have to restructure your data to long format. In ggplot2, data structure required for plotting is not like excel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [side-by-side barplot with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084775/side-by-side-barplot-with-ggplot)

Answer (score 0):

After pivoting your data, you can use `position = "dodge"` to get your groups side-by-side.

```
dat %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "period", values_to = "score") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = score, group = period, fill = period)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% pivot_longer(cols = 1:2) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(value, color = name), position = "dodge", fill = "grey")
```

[image]