# Simplest way to plot dataframe with one row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

What the simplest way to make a bar plot of the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(val1=10, val2=50)
```

I want to plot the `10` and `50` on y-axis, and `val1` and `val2` on x-axis correspondingly.
ggplot asks for aes but since there are no row names and I want to plot column names as x-values it gives an error.

Is there an easy way to do it without modifying the dataframe itself?

Comment: Had there been rownames you would have still been unable to draw  barplot.  You have to reshape your data first. There are numerous questions on SO showing how to do this.

Comment: Try this `library(tidyverse);

df <- data.frame(val1=10, val2=50);

df %>%
  gather() %>%
  ggplot(aes(key, value))+
  geom_col()`

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67261385/2884859) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66451364/2884859) for reference

Comment: `plot(rev(stack(df)))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks! This is most like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps converting `df` to a named vector and feeding it to `barplot()`:

```
barplot(unlist(df))
```

[image]